# Как вывести счетчик цикла в атрибут тега

Tags: razor, mvc, asp.net-mvc

Вот надо мне в цикле описать несколько div'ов и для каждого из них сгенерировать id с счетчиком из цикла.

```
@{ int index = 0; }
@foreach (var item in Model.Adresses){
   <div class="adress-container" id="AdressContainer">
   </div>
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы id-и дивов были вида AdressContainer0, AdressContainer1, ...?

Варианты

```
id="AdressContainer@index"
id="AdressContainer@{index.toString();}"
```

не работают.

Comment: Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете сделать, например, так:

```
@{
    int i = 0;
}
@foreach(var item in MyCollection) 
{        
    <div id="Address@(i++)" >
        qwerty
    </div>
}
```